# Best way to manipulate the string inside a JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

I have a JSON array built from objects added to a JSON object which I would like to slightly modify to get in the desired format.

Code Snippet:

```
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray();
        Object col = "name";
        Object num = 3;
        Object val = "{set:" + num + "}";
        jobj.put(col, val);
        jarr.add(jobj);
        System.out.println("what is jarr: " +jarr);
```

The output for the above code is the following:

```
what is jarr: [{"name":"{set:3}"}]
```

And, I would like the jarr array to be in this way instead:

```
 [{"name”:{“set”:”3”}}]
```

Using a `\"` or `'"'` is including that character as well. Also, I am not able to get rid of the enclosing double quotes for the value of `name`. It is always recognizing it as a string and adding the enclosing double quotes for `{set:3}`.

Is there a good way to get the jarr in the above-mentioned format?

Comment: If you want to get `"key": {...}` instead of `"key":"{...}"` format you should assign to `key` actual *json object*, not a String (even if that String would *represent* "state" of that object, it will be still a String). Something like `Object val = new JSONObject().put("set", num);` (depending on JSON library you are using).

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo that works